# Convert '\n' character from string to newline in java using regex

Tags: java

String i/p - `Hello\n world!! \nWelcome!!`

Op -

```
 Hello

 World!!

 Welcome!!
```

If \n occurs word will be printed on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a regular expression when wanting to replace one exact thing with one other exact thing, of course.

```
String in = "Hello\\nworld!!\\nWelcome!!";
String out = in.replace("\\n", "\n");
System.out.println(out);

> Hello
> World!!
> Welcome!!
```

If you want blank lines in between, replace with `"\n\n"` instead.

Comment: `\\n` should be escaped like `\\\\n`

Comment: @TechBIT, no it should not. This is `replace`, not `replaceAll`.